# Javascript Automatic changing text animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am trying to build a website and I need to create a new heading which changes automatically
like:-

```
"H" and then "He" and then "Hel" and then "Hell" and "Hello" and so on...
```

like an animation type stuff
my earlier code was:-

```js
let Str = "Hello Guys, Welcome to my website";
for (i = 0; i < Str.length; i++) {
  let string = Str[i]
  setTimeout('document.getElementById("Header").innerHTML += \'' + string + '\';', 100 * i);
}
```

It works but I need to remove that text too 
to add the new text

Comment: That code work.... which is the problem? are you sure your id is Header and not header?

Comment: Sorry I meant that I have to remove that text too to add other text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you're looping through the string to output each letter individually.

But what you need to do is to get small parts of the string. First round only the first letter, second time the first 2 letters, and so on. You can do this with the `substring` method on the string.

And because you want to repeat the loop, until all characters are printed, I'd suggest that you use `setInterval` with `clearInterval` to create a loop with a fixed amount of time between each iteration and stop the interval when a condition is met.

```js
const title = document.getElementById('title');
const text = "Hello Guys, Welcome to my website";

const animateText = (text, element, intervalDuration) => {
  let count = 0;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const part = text.substring(0, ++count);
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      element.textContent = part;
    });
    if (count === text.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, intervalDuration);
};

animateText(text, title, 100);
```

```html
<h1 id="title"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

make use the `subString` method

```
let Str = "Hello Guys, Welcome to my website";
for (i = 1; i < Str.length; i++) {
  let string = Str.substring(0, i)
  setTimeout('document.getElementById("Header").innerHTML = \'' + string + '\';', 100 * i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var headersToAnimate = ["Hello Guys, Welcome to my website", "Just kidding go float yourself"];
var startReversAnimationAfter = 500; //ms

function reverseAnimation(headerIndex){
  var i = headersToAnimate[headerIndex].length -1, delay = 0;
  for (; i >= 0 ; i--, delay++) {
    let string = headersToAnimate[headerIndex].substr(0, i);
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("Header").innerHTML = \'' + string + '\';', 100 * delay);
  }
  
   setTimeout(function(){ animateHeaders(headerIndex + 1)}, 100 * delay + startReversAnimationAfter);
}
function animateHeaders(headerIndex){
  var i =0;
  if(headerIndex ==  headersToAnimate.length){
    headerIndex = 0;
  }
  for (; i < headersToAnimate[headerIndex].length; i++) {
    let string = headersToAnimate[headerIndex][i]
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("Header").innerHTML += \'' + string + '\';', 100 * i);
  }
 
 setTimeout(function(){ reverseAnimation(headerIndex)}, 100 * i + startReversAnimationAfter);
}

animateHeaders(0)
```

```html
<div id="Header"></div>
```